# For what other values of $a$ is $H_a$ a subset of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is NOT homework, but review for a test. This is part b of a 2-part question, where part a was to show that $H$ was a subspace of $V$. I have done that part successfully and need help with the second part.

Let $V$ be the vector space of functions defined on the real line, i.e. $$V = \{f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}.$$
Let H be the set of functions defined on the real line which satisfy $f(0)= 0$, i.e.  $$H=\{f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid f(0)=0\}.$$

(b) Let $H_a=\{f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid f(0)=a\}.$ You have just shown that $H_0$ is a subspace of $V$. For what other values of $a$ is $H_a$ a subspace of $V$? (Give an explanation.)

(What I think the answer is now): I believe that $NO$ other values of $a$ is $H_a$ a subspace of $V$ because the zero vector of $V$ is no longer included in $H_a$ unless $a=0$.

Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. $H_a$ is what is called an affine subspace: there is a vector subspace (namely $H_0$) such that for every $f,g \in H_a$, $f-g \in H_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Right. Assume it were to hold for some $\beta$. Then you would need an $f_{id}$ such that for $g\in H$,

$(g+f_{id})(0) = g(0) +f_{id}(0) =  g(0) = a$,

but this implies $f_{id}(0)\neq a$ and thus $f_{id}\notin H$